# Google Calendar API retrieving datetime

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I need to retrieve datetime info from Google Calendar API. I am looking into this [quickstart example](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python). It retrieves start time of the meeting in a string format.

```
for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        print(start, event['summary'])
```

How can I retrieve the time in datetime format, not in a string format. So I can extract out year, month, hour, minute etc. information.

EDIT: An example output from the above statement

```
2018-03-07T13:00:00-08:00
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the string that you want converted?

Comment: The [`datetime` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) explain how to parse strings into datetime objects. Since most internet APIs use JSON, which doesn't have a datetime type, you're often going to have to do this in your code.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `dateutil`? I think that there may be other methods. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modified script :

```
import dateutil.parser

for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        parsedDate = dateutil.parser.parse(start)
        print(parsedDate, event['summary'])
```

#### Reference :

- [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/1.5)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.